# Android: Finding Log print source

Tags: android, android-logcat

Scattered through my code are Log statements.  I want to get rid of many of these, without having to go through each file and searching with `Ctrl+f` to find the Log statement sources.  Is there an easier way?

Edit: I am using Android Studio if that makes any difference!

Edit 2: The scenario would be when I want to find where a Log statement is coming from - say in the case where I see one printed in Logcat and I want to know its source without going through each file

Comment: use bash `find . -iname *.java | xargs grep -n Log`

Answer (score 0):

Use replace all button and leave replace with blank.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want to know the location in code of each Log statement, go to that statement, and then determine if I want to delete the Log

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks Can't you do that by using Find? it loops through matches following order of appearance in the file.

Comment: I could but I was hoping for an easier way - see my edit for my scenario

Comment: that's wrong. This replace will erase just Log., leaving the remaing string, causing a compile time error for every match